# JSON schema: Enforce array conent by options

Tags: arrays, json, schema

I am having a JSON array for which I would like to enforce it's contents.

Let's say I have four object types `A, B`, and `C` and `D`. My array may contain an arbitrary number of items from either type `A, B, C` or `string`. `D` or other types are however not allowed.

i.e.

- `[A, B, C, A, A, B, "stuff", "morestuff", C]` is valid
- `[A, A, 3, C]` is not valid (contains number 3)
- `[A, D, A, B]` is not valid (containts D)

Reading the [spec](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html) it looks as if this is not possible. There is only tuple validation and list validation.
However with tuple validation a) the order matters and b) there can not be an arbitrary number of objects of the same type. List validation fails as there are objects of different types.

Is this really not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible by using array of types as type for items:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": [A, B, C, "string"]
  }
}
```

reference:

Array's items type:
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#list-validation

more than one option for a type:
http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/type.html

Comment: thanks! should've read the documentation more carefully.